# ppd file for deskjet 1050

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, scanner, manjaro, proprietary-drivers

I'm on manjaro, I have deskjet 1050 printer/scanner. I installed hplip from AUR for the scanner to work.

It asks me for ppd file for deskjet 1050, what's a ppd file and how to get it?

It's [this one](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02190668), HP Deskjet 1050 All-in-One Printer - J410a, the first one in the table

Comment: Can you please provide more information on your Printer, ie the name printed below the Power Button or the name written on the Windows Driver Install CD, a,d I can direct you properly.

Comment: @eyoung100 please read my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but I have bad news:

1. Start at the [Linux Foundation Open Printing Project Database](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/database/databaseintro).
2. Click [Printer Listing](http://www.openprinting.org/printer_list.cgi).
3. On the Printer Listing Page, choose Manufacturer: HP, and Model: deskjet 1050 j410a.
4. Click Show This Printer, and arrive at [this results page](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-deskjet_1050_j410a)

The results Page states:

> Color inkjet printer, this is a Paperweight

and later:

> Miscellaneous Printer supports PJL.
>   Printer supports direct text printing with the 'us-ascii' charset.

PJL or [Printer Job Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Job_Language) is the low level language written to interface with the print queue.  Direct Printing with `us-ascii` gives you the option to print using the `lpd` command.  In short, there is *no ppd file for this model*

---

Now for some good news:
Typing the model directly into Google yields the [HP Linux Imaging and Printing: Print, Scan and Fax Drivers for Linux](http://HP%20Linux%20Imaging%20and%20Printing%20Print,%20Scan%20and%20Fax%20Drivers%20for%20Linux) support matrix for your model.

If you'll look down at the last table, titled **Other Information**, you'll see Driver Plugin: None, and See Note 8.  Driver Plugin is Code for PPD, and Note 8 explains there isn't one (which we just discovered following the steps above).  As such, I believe you can press Enter to leave the PPD item blank.  If asked later, you can use the model's dat name.  This will at least allow the printer to function via CUPS queue, but everything printed will come out in Black and White using the ASCII Character Set.

---

In answering this for you, I must say I've lost respect for HP, as most of their devices are well supported in Linux.  If printing in ASCII isn't acceptable for you, use the database link above to find a supported model in the HP Family, or go with a different brand.  I can't vouch for Epson through experience, but from what I've read, their models are well supported also.

Comment: I hate HP too, I discovered how much hp suck when i first installed linux, no printer support, no wifi support for their integrated wireless cards, sound card support suck, graphic card support suck, my graphic card used to crash so many F*** times and so on, i never really knew how much HP suck until I left windows messed up world

Comment: and one more thing, I don't really talk about it, but since you did, in your bio, I also have cerebral palsy, and very few in my country have normal life, the rest are just pathetic roles and stay at home, i have no sympathy whatsoever for anyone who has cerebral palsy, they are 1000 times better than hawking, i wish they can learn from you and the blind programmers i see on stackoverflow and stop depending on others to live