# Which printer manufacturers have put in the effort to have solid Linux support?

Tags: linux, drivers, cups, printer

I run Linux exclusively (home and business). I have standardized on HP printers because the HP driver works well. I don't have to worry about any driver issues.

However, now I am thinking about purchasing a different brand printer for the first time in years. I would like to know which printer manufacturer(s) have put in the effort to have solid Linux support.

(In case it is relevant, here is the printer I'm considering: Brother Printer MFC-L8850CDW Wireless Color Laser Printer with Scanner, Copier and Fax.)

Comment: Look in your distros package manager for printer drivers pacakage and printer spooler drivers. Then install and reoot.

Comment: I went through this process recently, and settled on a Samsung C460FW; all its features (printing, scanning, over wired or wireless) work out of the box on Linux, with no drivers from Samsung, just a PPD (it's a PostScript printer). It even has a built-in web server to check on the consumables etc.!

Comment: @StephenKitt - thanks for the recommendation. I will check that printer out. Probably off topic here, but I'm also hearing that the newest generation of inkjet printers are fast and low cost compared to color lasers.

Comment: I ended up sticking with HP. I bought an HP x551dw and it is the most impressive printer I have ever owned (for my specific requirements, obviously). I liked it so much I bought a second one a week later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Always Start Here When Buying A New Printer

1. Start at the [Linux Foundation Open Printing Project Database](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting/database/databaseintro).
2. Click [Printer Listing](http://www.openprinting.org/printer_list.cgi).
3. On the Printer Listing Page, choose Manufacturer: Brother, and Model: MFC-L8650CDW
4. Click Show This Printer, and arrive at [this results page](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-MFC-L8650CDW)

---

Put the page in Step 1 in your Bookmarks, and do some more research... As you can see from your results page, you want to research until you find a Printer that states Fully Supported.  Completely go down the list of your chosen printers resetting the manufacturer and model until you find one. All in All, HP is well supported unless it's an off the wall model, but the above database will tell you so.

See [An Off the Wall Model](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210112/ppd-file-for-deskjet-1050/211403)